# unable to get checked property of htmlinoutcheckbox on server side(code behind)

Tags: html, asp.net

I have created a html input check-boxes dynamically from code behind and after rendering the check-boxes on to aspx page I'm unable to get the checked property of those check-boxes on button click event. week is the enum with alldays of a week. Here the sample code.

```
HtmlInputCheckBox chkbx = new HtmlInputCheckBox();
chkbx.Attributes.Add("id", ((week)i).ToString());
chkbx.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
chkbx.Attributes.Add("name", ((week)i).ToString());
chkbx.Attributes.Add("value", "checked");

HtmlGenericControl label = new HtmlGenericControl("label");
label.Attributes.Add("for", ((week)i).ToString());
if (i == 1 || i == 7)
{
    label.Attributes.Add("class", "dow disabled");
    label.Attributes.Add("disabled", "true");
}
else
{
    label.Attributes.Add("class", "dow");
    chkbx.Checked = true;                    
}
label.InnerText = ((week)i).ToString().Substring(0,2);
_dowcontrol.Controls.Add(chkbx);
_dowcontrol.Controls.Add(label);
```

ASPX page

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" method = "post">
        <t2:mycontrol ID="SampleControl" runat="server" >
        </t2:mycontrol>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
    </form>
</body>
```

ASPX.CS page
What should be inside button click?

Tried

```
Request.Form["***"], FindControl("***")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for your dynamically created controls to interact with viewstate, events and other stages in the page life-cycle, they need to be created in the `Init` event. Creating these controls later in the life-cycle will exclude them from taking part in post value binding, viewstate binding, etc. Also note that you must recreate the controls on EVERY postback.

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do any dynamic control re/creation here.
}
```

Comment: the above .cs code is written in createchildcontrols in another class which inherits control & Inamingcontainer classes. and the all the markup code is present in another aspx page.

Comment: `createchildcontrols` is too late. You need to recreate the controls in the `Init` event. Look at the life-cycle of a custom control: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719775(v=vs.71).aspx